# raster::crop not working as expected

Tags: raster, r, polygon, clip, environment-variable

I'm trying to crop a [raster](http://chelsa-climate.org) stack using a polygon.

```
structure(chelsa_envs)
```

> class      : RasterStack
> dimensions : 20880, 43200, 902016000, 19  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
> resolution : 0.008333333, 0.008333333  (x, y)
> extent     : -180.0001, 179.9999, -90.00014, 83.99986  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
> crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs
> names      : CHELSA_bio10_01, CHELSA_bio10_02, CHELSA_bio10_03, CHELSA_bio10_04, CHELSA_bio10_05, CHELSA_bio10_06, CHELSA_bio10_07, CHELSA_bio10_08, CHELSA_bio10_09, CHELSA_bio10_10, CHELSA_bio10_11, CHELSA_bio10_12, CHELSA_bio10_13, CHELSA_bio10_14, CHELSA_bio10_15, ...
> min values :          -32768,          -32768,          -32768,          -32768,          -32768,          -32768,          -32768,          -32768,          -32768,          -32768,          -32768,          -32768,          -32768,          -32768,          -32768, ...
> max values :           32767,           32767,           32767,           32767,           32767,           32767,           32767,           32767,           32767,           32767,           32767,           32767,           32767,           32767,           32767, ...

my polygon:

```
structure(mcp)
```

> class       : SpatialPolygons
> features    : 1
> extent      : -46.72182, -32.46476, -25.44597, -1.358246  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
> crs         : NA

[image: MCP polygon]

I'm trying this code:

```
envs = raster::crop(chelsa_envs, mcp)
```

but I'm getting "no non-missing arguments to min (and max); returning inf" errors.

Example of one of the resulting rasters (visually different from the polygon):

[image: resulting raster]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try using the extent `raster::crop(chelsa_envs, raster::extent(mcp))`. If you are wanting a mask, clipped to an irregular polygon, you can nest everything using  `raster::mask(raster::crop(chelsa_envs, raster::extent(mcp)),mcp)`

Comment: Cant get that error with some test cases including a polygon nowhere near the raster or a raster full of NA. Can you show some info about your raster and polygon, such as their extent, raster resolution, coordinate system and anything else relevant?

Comment: @Spacedman structure added

Comment: I'm suddenly getting the same error with raster::projectRaster and other functions, even though the code previously worked fine. I wonder if it is being caused by a recent update.